# Call the corresponding data from a name propertie

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, properties

currently I'm trying, to fill a Chart with values. For that I'm using chartkick, vuejs and uibuilder v2.0 vor node red.

The data is declared like:

```
var app1 = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {// Area chart
    LeistungHakData: [
        {name: 'Wirkleistung', data: []}],
```

I try to push the Array containing the values via

```
vueApp.LeistungHakData.Wirkleistung.data.push( new Array( (new Date(newVal.payload[0])), newVal.payload[1] ) );
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
0: Unable to get property 'data' of undefined or null reference
```

Sincerly Dieter

Comment: `vueApp.LeistungHakData` does not have a `Wirkleistung` property. Perhaps you meant to do something like `vueApp.LeistungHakData.find(o => o.name === "Wirkleistung").data`?

Comment: `.Wirkleistung` does not have a property called Wirkleistung, it is an array ... so it'd be `LeistungHakData[0].data.push`

Comment: Thanks, Yeah it is an Array, the HTML DOC works now without sending an Error message. But the values are still not present.
I'm sure, that the .push() works because I've tested it with single line Charts and then everything is fine.